# I need help solving this differential delay equation (inverse Laplace transform problem)

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Let us consider a differential delay equation (DDE) with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$
\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=ay(t)+bH(t-1)y(t-1),~0\le t<\infty,
$$

where $H(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t\delta(t')dt'$ is the Heaviside step function. Let $\hat{y}(s)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}y(t)dt$ be the Laplace transform of $y(t)$.

- i). Find $\hat{y}(s)$ and, using the inverse Laplace transform, solve the given DDE.

**Here is what I have tried so far**:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left(\frac{d}{dt}y(t)\right)(s)&=\mathcal{L}\left(ay(t)+bH(t-1)y(t-1)\right)(s)\\
s\hat{y}(s)-y(0^{-})&=a\hat{y}(s)+be^{-s}\hat{y}(s),
\end{aligned}
$$

therefore

$$
\begin{aligned}
s\hat{y}(s)-a\hat{y}(s)-be^{-s}\hat{y}(s)&=y(0^{-})\\
\hat{y}(s)\left(s-a-be^{-s}\right)&=y(0^{-})\\
\hat{y}(s)&=\frac{y(0^{-})}{s-a-be^{-s}}\\
y(t)&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\hat{y}(s)\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}e^{st}\hat{y}(s)ds\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{y(0^{-})e^{st}}{s-a-be^{-s}}ds\\
&=\frac{y(0^{-})}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^{st}}{s-a-be^{-s}}ds
\end{aligned}
$$

**I need help: I don't know how to get the exact value of the inverse Laplace transform of** $\hat{y}(s)$

Comment: You might look in the book "integrals and series" by Prudnikov for this inverse Laplace transform. It will definitely not be expressed as an elementary function.

Comment: By a Tauberian theorem you can see that for large t (small s) the solution is $y_2(t) \sim e^{(a+b)t/(1+b)}$ whereas for small $t$ it's $y_1(t)= e^{at}$. So you have a type of exponential growth which changes rates.

Comment: Inverse Laplace transform of $\hat{y}(s)$ is $$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{b^j e^{a (-j+t)} (-j+t)^j H (-j+t) y(0^{-})}{\Gamma (1+j)}$$